# What is the difference between insert and insertSelective in MyBatis Generator?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

`insertSelective` allows us to insert only into specified columns, but isn't it the same as `insert`, when we keep an object's attributes null which we do not want to insert into the columns?

For example, if a `User`

```java
class User{
  Integer id;
  String name;
  String address;
}
```

What is the difference between `insert(User{null,"Jack",null}` and `insertSelective(User{null,"Jack",null}`?

Comment: It is explained in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/generator/generatedobjects/sqlmap.html#insert-selective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `insert()` and `insertSelective()` is that `insert()` will insert all columns specified in the object, including null values, while `insertSelective()` will only insert non-null values.

So, in your example, if you used `insert(User{null,"Jack",null})`, it would insert a new row with null values for the `id` and `address` columns. If you used `insertSelective(User{null,"Jack",null})`, it would only insert a new row with the non-null value of "Jack" for the `name` column.